# In Swift, is Key-Value Coding available for custom objects without subclassing NSObject?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, key-value-coding

In [Key-Value Coding Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107-SW1) it states NSObject subclasses are KVC compliant.

> Swift objects that inherit from NSObject or one of its subclasses are key-value coding compliant for their properties by default

Can custom objects(struct, classes) adopt `NSKeyValueCoding` and be KVC compliant?
Also, how is KVC given to an object just by subclassing NSObject?

Comment: I'm embarrassed. I deleted my "KVO" answer -- please ignore! ;-)

Comment: No problem, the two are so confusing cause of the abbreviations are so similar! @joeybladb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike a formal protocol, that any object could technically conform to, `NSKeyValueCoding` is available to any `NSObject` via [Informal Protocols:](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Protocol.html)

> An informal protocol is a category on NSObject, which implicitly makes
>   almost all objects adopters of the protocol. (A category is a language
>   feature that enables you to add methods to a class without subclassing
>   it.) Implementation of the methods in an informal protocol is
>   optional. Before invoking a method, the calling object checks to see
>   whether the target object implements it. Until optional protocol
>   methods were introduced in Objective-C 2.0, informal protocols were
>   essential to the way Foundation and AppKit classes implemented
>   delegation.

This is as opposed to simply implementing the KVC directly into `NSObject`, I think the main benefit of the informal protocol is to split up the functionality of `NSObject` into separate files.  But there may be other benefits of using Informal Protocols

And because `NSKeyValueCoding` is a category on `NSObject`, you unfortunately cannot just make any custom object support KVC

Comment: You *could* make a custom non-`NSObject` inheriting class (on Apple platforms) support KVC – you just need to implement (and expose to Obj-C) the methods detailed by the informal `NSKeyValueCoding` protocol. Not that I would ever recommend doing that besides for a learning exercise though.

Comment: @Hamish could you post an example of this? If it is possible that would be the correct answer. I am asking about the possibility of it in Swift without NSObject subclass and how it "just" works on an NSObject.

Comment: Interesting point, how would you do this?    I didn't think you could?
 Because `NSKeyValueCoding` is actually a category (aka informal protocol in this context), it's implementation is already done.  So short of just overriding `-setValue:forKey:`, and whatever else, I don't think you can just make any custom object conform right?

Comment: Here's a (really) crude example of how you could do it (it doesn't take into account property setting and bunch of other things): https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/3e804b9ba9e722c84551f3fef0183d0f.

Comment: @AO so KVC "just" works on NSObjects because the informal protocol is already implemented?

Comment: @AO can you point to any documentation or answer how that works under the hood? I am guessing it is done by mapping the selectors with key/key value paths.

Comment: A slightly related observation I made a couple of weeks ago: if you store basic Swift value types (String, Int, Double etc) in an NSDictionary, and then encode and decode the dictionary, those value types are properly (de)serialized. I also noted that Swift 4 will most likely have a new 'Coding' protocol which will make Swift objects and structs play well with KVC.

Comment: Correct, it is better to think of an informal protocol as a category, or a named extension of a class.  It's just pulling out implementation from one file into another.

Hamish's implementation looks interesting, but I think isn't what you're looking for because he has to define the keys, ("d" and "f")

I would guess that the KVC implementation utilizes the runtime to determine if an object responds to a key

something like: `object_getIvar(customObject, class_getInstanceVariable([customObject class], @"keyName"));`  Unfortunately I am not familiar with swift so I may not be relevant

Comment: Basically, what you're trying to do, is set a property on a custom object, without having a direct reference to that custom object's class.  KVC would allow you to say `-setValue:"matt" forKey:"name"`, and at runtime it would check your custom object for the `name` property, and then set it to `matt` if it exists.  All without needing to `#import Human.h`

So I'd recommend looking into the runtime,h and seeing if you can do something there.  I've never done it, but that's my best guess as to how KVC is implemented.  Also try reading Mike Ash's blogs, he writes about this stuff in depth

Comment: @AO You could also leverage the Obj-C runtime in my case, provided you were looking up properties that were also exposed to Obj-C (unfortunately, that therefore restricts you to properties with types that are `NSObject` inheriting or Obj-C directly bridgeable). The class itself could still be non-`NSObject` inheriting though, as on Apple platforms Swift classes are Obj-C classes under the hood.

Comment: @Hamish you can use Swift's `#keyPath` in your gist. `#keyPath(D.f)`

Comment: @lostAtSeaJoshua But not `#keyPath(C.d.f)`, as `d` is not directly exposed to Obj-C.